# Extjs: Alert message box position

Tags: extjs, messagebox

I am using the Extjs Messagebox in my application. When the Message box appears on screen, it appears at centre but when I minimize my window and again maximize it the message box shifts to top left position. How to fix the position of message alert box in Extjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.MessageBox.center()` puts the message box back in the center of the screen.  You may be able to plug in a `windowresize` listener that centers it after resize.